# AWS lambda getting handler or context information in node js

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, sdk

I am having a SDK which i include in my lambda function.
This SDK is responsible for gathering information about the context of lambda function and sends it to my remote server.
Below is my sample lambda code

```
import mymodule 

 exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
    var array = [];
    var count = 11000000; //loop to max number just to make sure we hit the limit
  // var count = 110000
    const str = "This is the memory error, will get the memory error.";
    
    //Start appending array with the string  
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
      array.push(str);
    }
  
    console.log(array);
  };
```

in my SDK code
i am capturing lambda_bootstrap by following statement

```
lambda_bootstap = require.main
```

this returns me majority of the parameters but dose not return the context
any help to get lambda context in my SDK would be great. TIA

Comment: Note that an async handler should not use the `callback` parameter. Use `async` or `callback`, not both.

Comment: thats in lambda function, but what about getting the context of lambda inside my sdk code

Comment: *You* need to provide the context to your SDK. You can do it explicitly, or via some middleware solution.

Answer (score 1):

You are importing `mymodule` at the module-level which means your SDK will be instantiated **outside** of an invocation context. So your SDK will be called only during the cold start and not in every invocation. `context` is only available *within* the invocation itself.

If you wish to get the `context` (which varies in every invocation), you have to call your SDK *inside* the handler.

What you essentially need to do is to create a wrapper for the Lambda handler so that you can call your SDK in each invocation. [Middy JS](https://github.com/middyjs/middy) provides with you with [some patterns on how to do this](https://github.com/middyjs/middy#writing-a-middleware).

Comment: Good recommendation on middy.